# How to disable emission at runtime

Tags: unity

I'm changing shader at runtime.

I don't know why, when i "load" Standard shader, Emission is 'flagged' on .

So I'm asking you: how can I disable emission ?

Getting material, I can change emission color with this code, but i want to disable emission at all.

```
Material mymat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
         mymat.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.red);
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting your emissive colour to black? Or [DisableKeyword](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.DisableKeyword.html)?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution as suggested from DMGregory is setting black color as the emission color:

```
Material mymat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
mymat.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.black);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this line creates a copy of your material. If you want to toggle emission frequently, then you might want to create two material assets and swap between them, to avoid creating unnecessary copies or splitting your draw calls more than necessary (if on the built-in pipeline).

Comment: Another alternative to creating a lot of materials which differ only by one property (either as assets or implicitly via code) is by using a [material property block](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html).